# Where can I find PyQt5 Method Signatures?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, method-signature, keyword-argument

I want to write a small application with graphical user interface and for that purpose I installed PyQt5. In a tutorial I found a QMessageBox.information(....) call is done.

I wanted to change the call, so that instead of:

```
QMessageBox.information(self, "Empty Field", "Please enter a name and address.")
```

I write keyword arguments, so that I know which of the parameters stand for which content, so that, when I read it in a year, I immediately know what it is about. So I tried:

```
QMessageBox.information(parent=self, title="Empty Field", message="Please enter a name and address.")
```

Which at execution time gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SimpleExample.py", line 39, in submitContact
QMessageBox.information(parent=self, title="Empty Field", message="Please enter a name and address.")
TypeError: QMessageBox.information(QWidget, str, str, QMessageBox.StandardButtons buttons=QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton): 'message' is not a valid keyword argument
```

So my guesses were wrong, but how do I figure out the real method signature?
I searched for a while and found this function:

```
from inspect import getcallargs
getcallargs()
```

I tried using it like this:

```
>>> from inspect import getcallargs
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import *
>>> getcallargs(QMessageBox.information(), a=1, b=2)
```

but that also doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: QMessageBox.information(QWidget, str, str, QMessageBox.StandardButtons buttons=QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton): not enough arguments
```

And no matter how many arguments I add (function 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, ...) it's never enough arguments. If it's talking about the arguments of information(), then how am I supposed to find the right amount of arguments of the very function I want to get the arguments for?!

So I thought "Ok lets try and see if I can find the method in the Qt5 docs." but of course, there I am only redirected to the c++ documentation for Qt5 and that one doesn't list a function "information()" for QMessageBox, so I still don't know the names of the keywords.

How can I figure out these names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PyQt, keyword arguments are only supported for *optional* arguments, so you cannot use them as general way of documenting function signatures.

A quick way to get the correct method signature, is to use the `help` function in a python interactive session:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import Qt
>>> help(Qt.QMessageBox.information)
...

Help on built-in function information:

information(...)
    QMessageBox.information(
        QWidget, str, str,
        QMessageBox.StandardButtons buttons=QMessageBox.Ok,
        QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton
    ) -> QMessageBox.StandardButton
```

This shows that only `buttons` and `defaultButton` are available as keyword arguments.

It's important that you do this, rather than looking at the Qt Docs for [QMessageBox.​information](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#information), because there is no guarantee that the C++ argument names will match the ones PyQt uses (for more details on this, see [Things to be Aware Of: Keyword Arguments](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#keyword-arguments) in the PyQt Docs).

PS:

The restrictions outlined above don't apply to PyQt's [Support for Qt Properties](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/qt_properties.html), which uses a different underlying mechanism. This functionality provides some Python-specific syntax-sugar which allows Qt properties to be set in the class contructor (via `**kwargs`, rather than named parameters).

In this particular case, it's possible to use this mechanism to achieve the desired behaviour because `QMessageBox` happens to have some [properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#properties) (if [inherited ones](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#properties) are included) that correspond with the relevant parameters in its constructor. However, they don't all have the *same names*, so you'd need to write something more like this:

```
result = QMessageBox(parent,
            icon=QMessageBox.Warning
            windowTitle='Error',
            text='Something went wrong!',
            ).exec()
```

But in general, its unlikely things will always work out so neatly.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I really was under the wrong impression that I could always use keyword arguments and that it is only a way to make things more readable.