# PyQt6: 'Title' keyword not recognized for QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt, signature, keyword-argument, pyqt6

I'm very new to PyQt, so it's possible I'm doing this entirely wrong. I'm currently struggling to set the `title` property of a `QMessageBox` during instantiation in PyQt6. Here is my code:

```python
import PyQt6.QtWidgets as Qtw

app = Qtw.QApplication([])
alert_window = Qtw.QMessageBox(text="Foo", title="Bar")
alert_window.exec()
```

When running this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'title' is an unknown keyword argument
```

However, `__init__` for `QMessageBox` (located in the Python stub `QtWidgets.pyi`) seems to clearly define `title` as a string argument, which I am passing correctly:

```python
@typing.overload
    def __init__(self, icon: 'QMessageBox.Icon', title: str, text: str, buttons: 'QMessageBox.StandardButton' = ..., parent: typing.Optional[QWidget] = ..., flags: QtCore.Qt.WindowType = ...) -> None: ...
```

I've tried to run this by removing the `title` keyword argument and just leaving `text` and it seems to work just fine. Am I missing something entirely, or is the `.pyi` file incorrect? And, if this file is incorrect, is there any other documentation for PyQt that I can reference to find which arguments I can and cannot use? Thanks.

Comment: See the PyQt6 Docs: [Keyword Arguments](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/gotchas.html#keyword-arguments). You can only use keywords with parameters that Qt explicitly defines as being *optional* (i.e. ones which have a default argument). (NB: this shouldn't be confused with [setting properties using keyword arguments](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/qt_properties.html#support-for-qt-properties), which involves an entirely different mechanism).

Comment: PS: I suppose I should also point out that in this particular case it's possible to do what you want because `QMessageBox` happens to have some [properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#properties) that correspond with the relevant parameters in its constructor. However, they don't all have the *same names*, so you'd have to write, e.g. `QMessageBox(text='Some important text', windowTitle='Foo')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues:

- you're confusing positional and named arguments;
- QObject *properties* can be used as named arguments;

### Positional vs. Named arguments

```py
def function(positional1, positional2, named1=something, named2=whatever):
```

The above means, simply put, that `function`:

- *requires* two arguments (`positional1` and positional2`);
- *can have* two optional arguments (`named1` and `named2`);

The positional arguments:

- are required when calling the function;
- must respect the order (and, possibly, their expected type);
- *their ***names*** are just for ***reference****;

The named arguments:

- are not required when calling the function;
- if not specified, use their default value, which is whatever is *evaluated* after the `=` sign;
- *might* be added **as** positional arguments, while respecting the order (`function(x, y, z)` means that `named1` will be equal to `z` within the function);
- might not be in the same order (`function(x, y, named2=z, named1=w)`);

The above means that calling `function(x)` will be correct, while `function(positional1=x)` will not.

### QObject properties

Almost all QObjects accept named arguments that correspond to the object's properties, even if they're not declared in the constructor's definition.

For instance, all QWidgets support the [`enabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop) property, meaning that you can do the following:

```py
button = QPushButton(enabled=False)
```

### The problem

Why this doesn't work?

```py
Qtw.QMessageBox(text="Foo", title="Bar")
```

That's for two reasons:

1. the `title` argument listed in the constructor is just a positional argument, so, as explained above, using a named argument `title="Bar"` is wrong;
2. `title` is **not** listed in [QMessageBox property list](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#properties) (nor in its inherited classes);

Why this *does* work?

```py
Qtw.QMessageBox(text="Foo")
```

This is for two reasons:

1. Among the QMessageBox constructors, there is one that also doesn't require positional arguments;
2. [`text()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#text-prop) is a valid Qt property of QMessageBox;

### Final notes

1. Don't use `pyi` stubs/definitions as reference; use the *documentation*, starting with the official C++ API (which is 99.9% the same as it's for Python) and eventually check the interactive Python console using `help(class.function)` for arguments and return values;
2. Do more careful research and study about function arguments in Python, including argument [un]packing (conventionally, `*args` and `**kwargs`);
3. PyQt (just as PySide) is a *binding*; it just wraps classes and functions that actually exist in the C++ side of the Qt library; that's why you can (and should) use the official C++ documentation instead of looking for the official PyQt one (or even the, sometimes misleading, PySide one) unless when strictly required;

Comment: Your "positional arguments" section is entirely wrong. In Python, calling `function(positional2='2', positional1='1')` won't raise an exception, thus contradicting all three of your bullet points. The OP isn't really confused here, because, *in Python terms*, calling `QMessageBox(text="Foo", title="Bar")` would normally be entirely correct. The real problem is that the bindings cannot fully resolve all the differences between the Python and C++ call syntaxes, so various work-arounds must be used (such as keyword support for object properties).

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for the correction, I realized that a couple of days ago (but I'm on travel and cannot properly update the answer), as I was thinking about the old syntax. I'll fix as soon as I come back on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

[Where can I find PyQt5 Method Signatures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469918/where-can-i-find-pyqt5-method-signatures)

It seems that you cannot use those as keyword arguments. You must do:

```py
alert_window = Qtw.QMessageBox("Foo", "Bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Where I see that you are having problems is in the arguments that you pass to `Qtw.QMessangeBox`.

You'd have to pass it this way: `alert_window = Qtw.QMessageBox("Foo", "Bar")`

Since you cannot assign variables to it with data within the argument, it has to be directly a variable already set in the Global or Local Scope or arguments written at the time.